# SQL multiple Select ... where id in and a DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-in

I am running a query with multiple "where id in" clauses on a table in a MySQL db. I put DISTINCT in each query to try to cut down the number of results. Still locked up my MySQL table. Any glitches I don't know about, or should I try getting rid of some of the DISTICTs? Only the first DISTINCT is necessary.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT id, name 
   FROM TP_Test_Info 
   WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT test_id 
                FROM TP_Test_Sections 
                WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT section_id 
                             FROM TP_Test_Questions 
                             WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT question_id 
                                          FROM TP_Student_Answers 
                                          WHERE student_id = 751)))
```

The last table TP_Student_Answers has about 32,000 entries. The rest are much smaller.

I realized that I should have indexed some of the rows in the big table. Spaced it. Any other problems stick out?

Comment: Why don't you try joins?

Comment: I have heard of JOINS. I did not know you could nest them like TI did below. Guess that is the difference between being helpful and being rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) and consider creating indexes at least on [foreign keys](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/benefits-indexing-foreign-keys)

Try the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT TP_Test_Info.id, TP_Test_Info.name
FROM TP_Test_Info
JOIN TP_Test_Sections 
  ON TP_Test_Sections.test_id = TP_Test_Info.id
JOIN TP_Test_Questions 
  ON TP_Test_Questions.section_id = TP_Test_Sections.id
JOIN TP_Student_Answers 
  ON TP_Student_Answers.question_id = TP_Test_Questions.id
WHERE TP_Student_Answers.student_id = 751
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using joins? I will use this, just wondering why that is advantageous.

Comment: The database engine will more easily optimize the query, making use of indexes etc. Plus `IN` is not exactly the best performing operator even though it 'makes sense', an alternative could be to use `EXISTS`. In your query when you think about it you are asking the database to do quite a lot of work to effectively check existence which is something that is - for the database - more naturally achieved with a join (think 'relational' not just 'logical'). Probably the best thing to do is to take a look at and compare the execution plans of the two queries to see how the database is handling them.

Comment: thanks! I am still trying to get my head around JOINS. I am a tutor, not a programmer, so this stuff is not really in my area of knowledge. Just do it for my own site.